# How can I get notified when a configuration value is added/changed/deleted?

Tags: configuration, blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

In Blazor server, running on Azure App Service, when I CrUD an environment property in the Azure App Service, how can I write my code to be notified of the change?

I read the config values when needed using:

```
[Inject]
protected IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = default!;
```

Will that read the latest each time a page loads and this is injected? Or do I need to tell it to refresh?

I also have it as a constructor parameter in some scoped services. Is there a way to have it get the latest value each time I access a config property?

Comment: I would ask why you're treating the environment properties as mutable in the first place.

Comment: @KurtHamilton In production users cannot create appointments in the past. But in QA, they need to be able to do that to then test actions taken on an appointment in the past. And once they create the appointments in the past, they then want it back in production rules.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a database for that...

Answer (score 0):

The IConfiguration injection you're using is pretty handy. When you read config values using [Inject] protected IConfiguration Configuration, it automatically gets the latest values each time a component is rendered or a service is instantiated. **No need to manually refresh it.**

Now, if you have it as a constructor parameter in scoped services, it's still all good. The injected IConfiguration will fetch the latest values when the service is created. So, accessing config properties in your services or components, **you're always getting the freshest data.**

Just keep doing your thing, and Blazor will seamlessly handle the config updates for you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a scoped service gets the values when created. But that service can be around for 1/2 hour or so as the user keeps active on the site. So they are then using settings as of 1/2 hour ago. Anyway to have it get the latest values when changed? TIA

Comment: Hey there! Absolutely get your concern about scoped services hanging around for a bit. If you want your scoped service to always get the freshest config values, you can inject IConfiguration directly into the method where you need it, instead of in the constructor.

Comment: Isn't there some way to register it so that it will auto-update when the config file changes?